# Feedback model for two rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have two models - `Customer` and `Contractors`. I have setup a simple app, where they interact on an `activity`. Now at the end of it, I would like for them to leave each other feedbacks. Nothing complex just a database field of `comment`.

I am wondering what is the right model association to have here?

I tried this

```
class Customer 
  has_many :feedbacks
end

class Contractor
  has_many :feedbacks
end

class Feedback
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :contractor
end
```

But the problem here is identifying who commented who.

For instance, if I do

```
customer = Customer.find(1)
contractor = Contractor.find(1)
customer.feedbacks.create(:comment => "Contractor 1 sucks", :contractor_id => 1)
```

The problem is, its accessible by both `contractor.feedbacks` and `customer.feedbacks`. And I dont know who commented who now.

Any guidance is appreciated. Am i missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Are companies or contractors the same thing? you seem to switch half way down

Comment: Yes, sorry I mixed up two things. I have updated my question.

Comment: Are you wanting some feedbacks to apply to both? You have, for example: `customer.feedbacks.create(:comment => "Contractor 1 sucks", :contractor_id => 1)` which is assigning the "Contractor 1 sucks" feedback to both the customer and to the contractor. Is that what you mean? BTW, I wouldn't do it that way anyway. I'd do something like `feedback = customer.feedbacks.create(:comment => "Contractor 1 sucks")`, and then assign it to the contractor with `contractor.feedbacks << feedback`.

Comment: no there arent any inside the system. I am trying to build one from scratch. Where customers can leave feedback for contractors and vice versa.

Comment: I don't think you understand my question. My question is: do you want to allow a single feedback that applies to both a customer and contractor?

Comment: nope, thats not how i want. Though @KyleMacey answered it really well for me. If you have a different way, would love to know it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do this would be to use [polymorphic associations](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association).

This way, you could have a `commenter` relationship, and a `commentable` relationship.

Like so:

```
class Customer 
  has_many :feedbacks, as: commenter
  has_many :feedbacks, as: commentable
end

class Contractor
  has_many :feedbacks, as: commenter
  has_many :feedbacks, as: commentable
end

class Feedback
  belongs_to :commenter, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Now, `Feedback` will require four new columns:

- `commentable_type:string`
- `commentable_id:integer`
- `commenter_type:string`
- `commenter_id:integer`

All four should be indexed, so write your migrations appropriately. The `type` columns will store a String value of the model name associated ("Customer" or "Contractor").

So you can do things like:

```
  @feedback = Feedback.find 3
  @feedback.commenter
    => # Some Customer

  @feedback.commentable
    => # Some Contractor
```

And vise versa. You would build like:

```
@customer = Customer.find 1
@contractor = Contractor.find 1
@feedback = Feedback.new comment: "This is a great Contractor"
@feedback.commenter = @customer  # You can reverse this for a contractor giving feedback to a customer
@feedback.commentable = @contractor
@feedback.save!
```

Comment: Hey Kyle, unfortunately the `customer_id` and `contractor_id` gets set to nil. Any clue why? The other two fields get save fine.

Comment: When done this inside the view `<%=@feedback.commentable.class%>` returns `NilClass`

Comment: I can help you more maybe Monday. I'm not going to be home until then. Edit your question with your code and your migrations. Watch the video at the first link in my answer, too. That should help answer a lot of issues.